# Mysql Function Coding

Tags: mysql, function

good day,
So I have been trying to code this function of mine that allows me to check and deduct then concatenate some data using the if function.
I've been trying to read the example syntax from the internet over and over again but I cant seem to find what is wrong with my code!

heres what I did:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `db`$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `convertToRelatives`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `BaseConverter`(n INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(100) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
  DECLARE s VARCHAR (100);

  IF n - 32 >= 0
  THEN SET s = 'Father'
  AND n = n - 32;
  IF n - 16 >= 0
  THEN SET s = CONCAT(s, ', ', 'Mother')
  AND n = n - 16;  

  END IF;
  RETURN s;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

and Im getting this error:

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13

so.. what exactly is wrong???

what I am trying to do is:

get the input number using the function and return a concatenated string.

my formula is:

```
if n-32 >=0 then s = 'father'
if n-16 >=0 then s = CONCAT(s,',','Mother')
if n-8 >=0 then s = CONCAT(s,',','Brother')
if n-4 >=0 then s = CONCAT(s,',','Sister')
if n-2 >=0 then s = CONCAT(s,',','Others')
```

help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `AND n = n - 32;` causing the issue. It should be

```
  IF n - 32 >= 0 THEN 
  BEGIN
  SET s = 'Father';
  SET n = n - 32;
  END;
 ELSEIF n - 16 >= 0 THEN 
 BEGIN
  SET s = CONCAT(s, ', ', 'Mother');
  SET n = n - 16;  
 END;
 END IF;
```

Comment: @jamescastillo, see update in answer. You have to correct the other if statement as well.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, I cant believe I missed that.